# Eliminar filas específicas

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe como este:

Chenopodium_album:

```
                    POS       Bp      Proportion       total    Ref 
                    042_T     T           4              6       T
                    042_T     C           2              6       T
                    051_A     A           5              6       A
                    051_A     G           1              6       A
                    061_A     A           5              6       A
                    061_A     G           1              6       A
                    069_A     A           5              6       A
                    069_A     G           1              6       A
```

Me gustaría eliminar aquellas filas que no correspondan la columna Bp con la columna Ref.
He utilizado esta función:

```
    Chenopodium_album$ref_1 <- ifelse(is.na(match(Chenopodium_album$Bp, Chenopodium_album$Ref)),0,1)
```

Para luego eliminar aquellas filas con un 0 pero me añade un 1 en todas las filas.
 ¿Cómo puedo eliminarlas?

Comment: Probé tu código, yo si obtengo 1 en caso de que Bp y Ref sean iguales y 0 en caso contrario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más simple es aprovechar que el operador de igualdad es vectorizado, por lo que puedes hacer

```
Chenopodium_album$Bp == Chenopodium_album$Ref

[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Esto básicamente te retorna un vector de lógicos dónde los `TRUE` indican aquellas filas dónde `Bp == Ref`, este vector puede usarlo para recortar el `data.frame`

```
Chenopodium_album[Chenopodium_album$Bp == Chenopodium_album$Ref,]

    POS Bp Proportion total Ref
1 042_T  T          4     6   T
3 051_A  A          5     6   A
5 061_A  A          5     6   A
7 069_A  A          5     6   A
```

El único inconveniente es la comparación de NA´s, ya que en la igualación ocurre que `NA != NA`, si quieres considerar que los `NA` son iguales puedes usar `match()` de la siguiente forma:

```
Chenopodium_album[match(Chenopodium_album$Bp, Chenopodium_album$Ref, nomatch = 0), ]

      POS   Bp Proportion total  Ref
1   042_T    T          4     6    T
3   051_A    A          5     6    A
3.1 051_A    A          5     6    A
7   069_A <NA>          5     6 <NA>
```

Comment: En ambos casos me ha funcionado, muchas gracias a los dos

Answer (score 2):

El siguiente código te puede ayudar,

```
df<-structure(list(POS = c("042_T", "042_T", "051_A", "051_A", "061_A", 
                            "061_A", "069_A", "069_A"), 
                   Bp = c("T", "C", "A", "G", "A", "G","A", "G"), 
                   Proportion = c("4", "2", "5", "1", "5", "1", "5","1"), 
                   total = c("6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6"),
                   Ref = c("T", "T", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A")),
              class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-8L))


df
    POS Bp Proportion total Ref
1 042_T  T          4     6   T
2 042_T  C          2     6   T
3 051_A  A          5     6   A
4 051_A  G          1     6   A
5 061_A  A          5     6   A
6 061_A  G          1     6   A
7 069_A  A          5     6   A
8 069_A  G          1     6   A

df[df$Bp==df$Ref,] #Filtramos solo las filas donde las columnas Bp y Ref son iguales.
    POS Bp Proportion total Ref
1 042_T  T          4     6   T
3 051_A  A          5     6   A
5 061_A  A          5     6   A
7 069_A  A          5     6   A
```